# How to Change The Width/Height Of A Search Box

Tags: html, css, search-engine

I'm having trouble with this form I was creating. I started working on a old project and decided to start fresh and scrap the code. The project was a recreation of the Google homepage design. I wanted to have an exact design, except for some things which aren't really needed. The search box (form) moved right where I wanted, but because of the new logo, I had to place my search box on the hand during the animation. The problem is that my coordinates are how I wanted it, but the height and width won't change. This is my whole entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Google</title>
        <style>
            .GoogleLogo {
                position:absolute;
                TOP:125px;
                LEFT:575px;
            }

            .SearchBar {
                position: absolute;
                top: 355px;
                left: 575px;
                height: 30px;
                width: 50px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="GoogleLogo">
            <a href="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Google+logo+history&hl=en&oi=ddle"><img src="../../Pictures/Google2.gif" alt="Google" width="400" height="231" border="0" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="SearchBar">
            <form>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</HTML>
```

Is there a way to change the height and width without 'damaging' anything. I want the class, `.SearchBar`, to respond to my coding of which I changed the height and width. I changed it to 550 pixels, and it still doesn't work, thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to change the with of the actual input element, you need to, well... change the width of the actual input element. You've changed the div, but not the input.

```
.SearchBar {
     position: absolute;
     top: 355px;
     left: 575px;
}

.SearchBar input {
     height: 30px;
     width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me, I would've never known about it. Thank you, again, I'm glad I was able to find an answer from this community.